# How to set a date variable with several days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a list of dates data. So far I'm only selecting one date at a time but I need it to be multiple days.

```
declare @evalDate1 as Date
declare @evalDate [date];
set @evalDate1 = '2020-10-20'
```

I tried this:

```
declare @evalDate1 as Date
declare @evalDate [date];
set @evalDate1 = ('2020-10-20' or '2020-10-21')
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: A variable can only hold a single value, so maybe you want a table valued variable? of course explaining what you are using it for would help understand the bigger picture.

Comment: Without more details I would suggest using two variables and using the  Between function to get the scope of days you want unless they are separated. The dates in your example are next to each other

Comment: Perhaps you are actually after a table variable, not a scalar variable.

Comment: T-SQL does not have arrays. Variables can only hold single values. (Unless you use XML or Json, at which point you are better off using some other system.) As per @eshirvana, consider using temp tables (# or @) to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

you either need to make  temp table

```
create table #evalDate ( value date)
    
insert into #evalDate values ('2020-10-20'), ('2020-10-21')
```

or a table variable

```
create @evalDate table ( value date)

insert into @evalDate values ('2020-10-20'), ('2020-10-21')
```